# Adding multiple instances of an object to another object's array;

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add multiple instances of different objects to another object's array.  I'm having trouble however.

```
*Creates the player*
function Player(){
    this.name = "";
    this.status = "Alive";
    this.primaryClass = null;
    this.secondaryClass = null;
    this.strength = 0;
    this.stamina = 0;
    this.mystica = 0;
    this.health = 0;
    this.primaryWeapon = null;
    this.offHand = null;
    this.accuracy = 0;
    this.block = 0;
    this.baseDamage = 0;
    this.maxDamage = 0;
    this.attackSpeed = 0;
    this.shield = null;
    this.armor = null;
    this.armorRating = 0;
    this.exp = 0;
}
*Creates the sword weapon*
function LongSword(){
    this.name = "";
    this.attackSpeed = 1;
    this.baseDamage = 10;
    this.maxDamage = 15;
    this.durability = 100;
    this.block = 5;
    this.exp = 0;
}
*Creates the Long Sword skills*
function Stab(){
    this.name = "Stab";
    this.status = "Unlocked";
    this.damage = 0;
    this.damageModifier = 0.75;
    this.cooldown = 5;
    this.exp = 0;
    this.desc = "Stabs your opponent for an additional " +parseInt(this.damageModifier * 100) +"% of your base damage.";
}
*Equips the Player weapon(s)*
Player.prototype.equipWeapon = function equipWeapon(main, offHand){
    if(this.primaryClass.dualWield){
        this.primaryWeapon = main;
        if(offHand){
            this.offHand = offHand;
            this.baseDamage += (this.strength + (main.baseDamage + (offHand.baseDamage / 2))) / 10;
            this.maxDamage += (this.strength + (main.maxDamage + (offHand.maxDamage / 2))) / 5;
            this.attackSpeed += main.attackSpeed + (offHand.attackSpeed / 2);
            this.block += main.block + offHand.block;
        }
    }
    else{
        this.primaryWeapon = main;
        this.offHand = null;
        this.baseDamage += (this.strength + main.baseDamage) / 10;
        this.maxDamage += (this.strength + main.maxDamage) / 5;
        this.attackSpeed += main.attackSpeed;
        this.block += main.block;
    }

    if(!this.primaryClass.dualWield && offHand){
        console.log("Your class can not wield dual weapons.");
    }
}
*Equips the Weapon skills*
LongSword.prototype.skills = function skills(skill){
    this.skills = [];
    skill.damage = parseFloat((this.baseDamage / skill.damageModifier).toFixed(1));
    this.skills.push(skill);
}
```

These objects construct the basic elements of what I'm trying to do.  So when I go to instantiate each one,

```
var Robert = new Player();
Robert.equipWeapon(new LongSword());
Robert.primaryWeapon.skills(new Stab());
```

I am getting the results I want.  However, if I were to try to add another instance of `Stab()` so that it looks like this

```
var Robert = new Player();
Robert.equipWeapon(new LongSword());
Robert.primaryWeapon.skills(new Stab());
Robert.primaryWeapon.skills(new Stab());
```

I get the TypeError: `Robert.primaryWeapon.skills is not a function`.  Why would it work correctly once, but not a second time.  The end result of which I'm trying to achieve is that if consoled out `Robert.primaryWeapon.skills`, I should see two instances of the `Stab` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your `Longsword`'s prototype.

First, you are replacing your function with your storing `skill` array, which have the same name :

```
LongSword.prototype.skills = function skills(skill){
    this.skills = []; //Overrides your function
    ...
```

Which leads to your error, `Robert.primaryWeapon.skills is not a function`, cause once you call it, it is an array indeed.

**To fix it, just change the name of one of the function or of the array.**

Secondly, you are initializing your `skills` array to an empty array each time you call the function, resetting it every time. You should initialize it in `Longsword`'s protoype.

---

Here's a an example with these fixes ([fiddle with it if you want](https://jsfiddle.net/gjda0tcb/)):

```
function LongSword(){
   this.skills = [];
   ...

LongSword.prototype.addSkill = function skills(skill){
    ...
```

Then, you'll be able to add multiple skills :

```
var Robert = new Player();
Robert.equipWeapon(new LongSword());
Robert.primaryWeapon.addSkill(new Stab());
Robert.primaryWeapon.addSkill(new Stab());
```

Comment: …and probably the `this.skills` array should be initialised in the <s>`Player`</s>`Weapon` constructor, not the `addSkill` method.

Comment: @Bergi, even if the skills is specific to the weapon?

Comment: It should then be on `Longsword` constructor.

Comment: @Bigood I figured that would make it easier to manage, I added it to the constructor.  Thanks

Comment: @Robert: Oops, you're right, it should be in the constructor of the `Robert.primaryWeapon`. Although I'm not sure why a weapon has skills, so that's probably where my initial confusion came from.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping me out guys